# Does an agent benefit from marks created by you?

Tags: shadowrun-sr5

I am making a decker character for the first time and I am looking into what is possible and what not. Now I'm curious of what is possible with agents, as indicated in the question.

The defintion of an agent is:

> Agent: a semi-autonomous program that is capable of taking independent actions in the Matrix.

So this means an agent is running on your cyberdeck.

A mark:

> A Matrix authentication recognition key is how the Matrix keeps track of which personas have access to which devices, files, hosts, and other personas.

A persona:

> A person in the Matrix. A persona is the combination of a user and a device that gets the user onto the Matrix.

**The situation**
Imagine I am in a hacking scenario. My character uses one of his deck's program slots to deploy an agent to assist him. I use the "Hack-on-the-fly" matrix action in order to get a mark on the device I am targeting. Then my agent uses "Data Spike" to brick it.

**Question: Does the agent benefit from the marks made by me?**
In this situation: does the agent get 2 additional DV boxes on a hit because of the marks? Or can marks made by me not used by the agent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### They do not

Only hosts and spiders are ever mentioned as being able to share marks, everything else has their own personas and thus do not share marks, including sprites and agents (autonomous or not).

See the Core Rulebook (p.235):

> Some personas are agents, performing tasks on behalf of their owners. Agents running alone on a device replace the device icon the same way a living user does. If you’re running an agent along with your persona, it appears with its **own separate persona**, even though you’re using the same device.

And also on Core Rulebook (pg.236):

> Your **marks are specific and connected to your persona** and whatever you’ve marked, so you can’t just give them out for others to place or transfer them to other people. You can give other personas permission to mark devices you own with the Invite Mark action.